# Find img height and write attribute - jquery

Tags: jquery

Trying to find the img height and apply inline as attr. Currently img only has src attr but want to dynamically find height and apply.

Current

```
  <img src="#">
```

Desired

```
<img src="#" height="find this images height">
```

This is what i have so far

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("img").load(function() {
 var width = $(this).width();
 var height = $(this).height() ;

 $(this).attr( "height", "+ height" );
 });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Comment: Not sure img.load() is always triggered in all browsers for cached image. Same for broken image. Could someone confirm or infirm?

Comment: yes i saw that post but i dont see how to apply it as a height attr to the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) :

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
>
> It doesn't
>   fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as
>   before
>
> It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree Can cease to fire
>   for images that already live in the browser's cache

You may use this :

```
var img = $('img').get(0); // no better selector ?
if (img.height) alert('height is '+img.height);
else img.onload = function(){alert('height is '+img.height)};
```

In a cleaner way :

```
function onImgLoaded(img, callback) {
   if (img.width) callback(img));
   else img.onload = function(){callback(img)};
}
onImgLoaded($('img').get(0), function(img){
    alert('height is '+img.height);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A little unclear here whether or not you need the height of the image before you write to the DOM. here's how to get the width & height with straight javascript:

```
var img   = document.getElementById('image_id'); 
var img_w = img.clientWidth;
var img_h = img.clientHeight;
```

here's how to do it with jQuery:

```
var img   = $("<img src='image_url' />");
var img_w = img.width;
var img_h = img.height;
```

good luck...

answer appended:

```
var img_h; var img_w;
var img = new Image();
img.src = img_src;
img_h   = img.height;
img_w   = img.width;
document.write( "<img src=" + img_src + " height=" + img_h + " />" );
```

Comment: Doesn't work if image isn't in cache as loading is asynchronous.

Comment: yes, i do need it to load before the DOM. its for a masonry layout, so without the images height set first the images overlap which is why I need to apply the height as an attr

Comment: then you're probably going to have to do it with some simply javascript and a document.write command. check my edit for code.